# What are the pros and cons for these approaches?

Tags: d3.js

What are the pros and cons for these two approaches?   What controls which way the bars fly in e.g. from top to bottom or left to right?  Why doesn't bar.exit().remove() work with Option 2?

Option 1
https://jsfiddle.net/2523onr3/
Option 2
https://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/2523onr3/3/

```
bar.exit().remove()

svg.selectAll(".bar").remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two substantially different approaches here.

The first option:

```
bar.exit().remove()
```

Is a proper "exit" selection. This is what it does:

Given your update selection...

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.label;
    });
```

... your exit selection compares the data with the selected DOM elements. If you have more elements than data, the extra elements (that is, the elements left without data) will populate this selection. Then, when you do `remove()`, you remove the elements present in this selection.

Before doing `remove()`, you can do any transition you want with your exit selection: moving right, left, up, changing colour, changing opacity etc. So, **you** control "which way the bars fly", not only in the exit selection but in the enter and update selections as well.

On the other hand, your second option...

```
svg.selectAll(".bar").remove();
```

... simply selects everything with a class named `bar` (it can be a circle, a text, a rectangle, a pentagon, it doesn't matter...) and remove all elements with that class.

Comment: PS: in your case the exit selection doesn't make much difference, because your data array has always 6 objects.

Comment: I'm still not clear why bar.exit().remove() doesn't work with option 2.  Both options include  bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(dataset).  Does the filter function(d) {return d.label; make the difference?   As you pointed out there are 6 objects in both cases, the values are change but not the labels.

Comment: The exit selection has to come after the data-binding selection. And, as I said, your exit selection is always empty. Also have in mind that I provided a general, theoretical answer, dealing with the logic of the approaches... Your question ("why this didn't work") requires a better explanation of the desired outcome (for instance, what labels are not changing?).

Comment: if I replace the class removal method with exit().remove() the bars remain after a change is made.  Just overwriting with the new bar causes a darkening of the original bar that can been seen  through the new bar.  But it is shifted by the axis change.  Is this what you would expect?

Comment: In your first fiddle, the exit selection does **nothing**: remove it and you'll see (I know this because I wrote those selections). In your second fiddle, unlike your first one, you're appending new rectangles every time you change the data. That's why you have to remove your previous elements. Don't do that, stick with the first fiddle.

Comment: Okay I see it does nothing until I add a new category 7 and then it is needed to update the selection.  The other difference I see is that I add rect to g element and transform translate but you use x and y placement which I thought wouldn't work and then you pick up the new coordinates during the transition on rect and bar whereas I transition the g element.  Is yours the most reliable method?

Comment: It's not more *reliable*, but it's always a good idea having a clear update, enter and exit selections.